# How does polarization influence selection rules?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

The transition probability for an optical transition is given by $p = |\textbf{d}_{ij}\cdot \textbf{E}|^2$, where $\textbf{E}$ is the electric field and $\textbf{d}_{ij} = e\langle \psi_i|\textbf{r} |\psi_j \rangle$ the transition dipole matrix element. As far as I understand, a transition is forbidden if $p=0$, but I don't really understand the role that the polarization of the light plays here. I understand that if the light is linearly polarized in $z$-direction, i.e. $\textbf{E} = E_0\cos (\omega t) \textbf{e}_z$, only transitions with a non-vanishing $d_z$ component ($\Delta m=0$) are allowed, since otherwise the dot product is zero.

Light that is circularly polarized in the $x$-$y$-plane is described by $\textbf{E}=E_0 (\cos(\omega t) \textbf{e}_x \pm \sin(\omega t) \textbf{e}_y)$ and therefore the transition probability is $p = |E_0|^2 |\cos(\omega t)d_x \pm \sin(\omega t) d_y|^2$. Now I have often heard that the degree of polarization ($\sigma^+$ or $\sigma^-$) matters for the kind of transitions that are allowed, but I don't see how the sign has an influence on whether the matrix element vanishes, especially since $\textbf{d}$ is not time dependent, right? Linearly polarized light (in $x$-direction) would also allow the transition to happen, as long as $d_x$ is non-zero?